# How to implement Nested Iframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I need to implement an Iframe inside an Iframe dynamically(I am making a demo, actually in real scenario i just can control the first parent page and second iframe parent page third  on  the child is a response which will return by server and its an Iframe).But I am not getting it how to do it as while creating another Iframe I am getting that for a second then the parent Iframe is loaded again.
Below what I have tried till:

```
 verifyUserCredential: function () {
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET", //HTTP GET Method
            cache: false,
            url: verifyCredUrl, // Controller/View
            data: { username: username, password: password },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.jvalue) {
                    //alert("Matched!!!");
                    UserLogin.getPaymentMethods();
                }
                else {
                   // alert("Not Matched!!!");
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                //AlertMessage("Error", AlertMessage4);
            }
        });
    }
```

The above code is verifying the credential and on success calling a method which will reload another Iframe.

```
 getPaymentMethods: function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET", //HTTP GET Method
            cache: false,
            url: paymentType, // Controller/View
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.jvalue) {
                    //alert("Matched!!!");
                    $("#prevDiv").hide();
                    $(data.jvalue).appendTo('body');

                }
                else {
                    // alert("Not Matched!!!");
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                //AlertMessage("Error", AlertMessage4);
            }
        });

    }
```

here data.jvalue is json return from server it a Iframe:

```
var jsonValue = "<iframe name='testiFrame' id='runtimeIFrame'  frameborder='no' scrolling='auto' height='400px' width='320px' src='http://google.com&output=embed?interframe=true'></iframe>";
```

[image: this is the main Page where first iframe form]

[image: this is the second page the iframe here i need to insert another iframe and hide login]

the src of iframe has below html:

```
 <div class="login-page " id="prevDiv">
        <div class="form formcustom">
            <form class="login-form">
                <input type="text" placeholder="username" id="username" />
                <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password"/>
                <button id="btnLogin">login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

<div id="dviframe">
//here i need to put new iframe and hide previous div
    </div>
```

Comment: Please explain WHY you need nested iFrames or this will just be an X/Y problem

Comment: @mplungjan have mentioned it.